# How to do code syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow does code syntax highlighting automatically, however, ai.stackexchange doesn't.

I've tried to add `<-- language: python -->` before code lines but no syntax highlighting applied.

How to do code syntax highlighting on ai.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website should rarely need this feature, given that we are mainly concerned with theoretical and philosophical AI questions. Most implementation-related questions are off-topic here. You can ask them on Data Science SE or Stack Overflow. See [Help Center > Asking > What topics can I ask about here?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).